# How do I vertically center an icon with a multiline text label's first line of text?

Tags: ios, swiftui, vertical-alignment

## Problem

We want an icon that is centered vertically with the first line of text of an adjacent view, and we want it to be aligned regardless of text length, icon size or font size. In other words, we want the following result:

[image]

The desired result is above: the red icon is aligned with the center of the first line of textIn SwiftUI, the default vertical alignment options are:

```
.top
.center
.bottom
.firstTextBaseline
.lastTextBaseline
```

`.center` is what we want for a single line of text, but if we use it for multiline text we get:

[image]

And if we use `.firstTextBaseline`, we are close but it doesn't quite center the image (this is more obvious as the text size changes):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

We need to use a combination of alignment guides and arithmetic. The solution in code is below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.red)
                .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
                .alignmentGuide(.firstTextBaseline) { context in
                    context[VerticalAlignment.center]
                }
            Text(greeting)
                .font(.title3)
                .background(.blue)
                .alignmentGuide(.firstTextBaseline) { context in
                    let remainingLine = (context.height - context[.lastTextBaseline])
                    let lineHeight = context[.firstTextBaseline] + remainingLine
                    let lineCenter = lineHeight / 2
                    return lineCenter
                }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example, the rectangle center is aligned with the center of the first line:

[image]

#### How it works

- The `Rectangle` is a stand-in for an icon.
- The `.firstTextBaseline` of `alignmentGuide` is actually only used as a key to match the against the `HStack` alignment. So it doesn't make a difference except that the `HStack`, `Rectangle` and `Text` all are using the same vertical alignment scheme.
- The `context[VerticalAlignment.center]` of the `Rectangle` is returned to indicate that the center of the `Rectangle` will be be aligned with the other alignment guides of its view siblings (thus centering the `Rectangle`)
- We need to do additional math for the `Text` to find where the center of the first line of text lies. The arithmetic uses the `lastTextBaseline` and the `height` of the entire `Text` to calculate the region below the text baseline. By adding this to the `firstTextBaseline` and dividing by 2, we determine where the center of the first line of text lies. The result of this calculation is returned as the alignment guide, for alignment with its siblings (in this case, the center of the `Rectangle` that we returned already)